# Java exception is a string after event.getSource().getException() and hard to catch because has to be parsed

Tags: java, exception, javafx

My code

```
        networkService.setOnFailed(event -> {
        Throwable exception = event.getSource().getException();
        System.out.println(exception);
        }
        )
```

makes it hard to verify that my exception is a certain type.
When I print it, I get this:
`myCustomException: File C:\Users\...\Documents\...\test\...zip does not exist or is not a regular file` and I would like to only get `myCustomException` to then only do something if it is indeed `myCustomException` and not another exception.

I guess I could use regular expressions to only get this out of this String but I think there might be a method to do this "more cleanly" if that makes sense. Especially if there is another exception that might respond poorly to my made-at-home regular expression parser.

Comment: `exception.printStackTrace()` perhaps, though I don’t understand what you are really asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but if you want to check the exception type,  why don't you just do `if (exception instanceof MyCustomException) { ... }` or `if (exception.getClass() == MyCustomException.class) { ... }`? If that's not what you're asking, clarify your question.

Comment: I've tried modifying the post to make a bit more understandable. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't. It's a `Throwable` - your code says it, right there: `Throwable exception`.

The `println` method has a few variants; one for each primitive (such as `double` and `int`); clearly not relevant here. Then one for `String`, that part is obvious. Finally, one for **any `Object`** - and what that will do is invoke the `toString()` method on the object you pass to it, and then print that.

That's what is happening here (as Throwables are also objects) - you're seeing the toString output. You should *never* use toString output as meaningful, it's a debugging aid, you should not be parsing it.

Here are a few things you can do:

```
if (exception instanceof MyCustomException) {
  MyCustomException customEx = (MyCustomException) exception;
  customEx.getCustomStuff();
}

exception.getClass() == MyCustomException.class // would be true
exception.getMessage();
```

and so on.

Comment: Note in Java 17 and later: `if (exception instanceof MyCustomException customEx) { customEx.getCustomStuff(); }`